# how to make an overlay caption on a liquid container

Tags: html, css

I am using Foundation framework, and I have a large-block-grid-4 set of images, I would like to have a div as a caption to cover the entire image that is inside a li tag, I have done my CSS and html but since the width of the container changes according to the screen size, I can't get the div properly fit into the li at all times
here is an example of the feature I am trying to do.
http://procreate.si
the HTML

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="large-12 columns">
 <ul class="large-block-grid-4">
 <li>
 <div class="overlay"></div>
 <a href="#">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/290X290" />   
</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/290X290" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/290X290" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/290X290" /></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
    </div>
```

and the CSS

```
      .overlay {
background:#000;
 opacity: 0.8;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.9s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.9s;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.9s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.9s;
transition: opacity 0.9s;
   }
     .overlay:hover {
   opacity: 1.0


    }
```

the caption div takes the whole width of the ul , this is not what I intended , what is the solution to this?
many thanks

Comment: Where is that code on your page?

Comment: it's a fragment of it

Comment: It's not really enough. Make up a complete example of what you have and make it clear what you want it to do. You can set the captions to width: 100% etc.